# Is there a way to solve for $x$ in $\cos(ax)/\cos(bx)=c$?

Tags: trigonometry

Is there a way to solve for x in $\dfrac{\cos(ax)}{\cos(bx)} = c$?

This is similar to [the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58939/is-there-a-way-to-solve-for-x-in-cos-1ax-cos-1bx-c) on $\dfrac{\cos^{-1}(ax)}{\cos^{-1}(bx)} = c$.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there is no way to find a closed form solution for $x$ in general.

Comment: Do you know anything about the ratio `a/b`?

Comment: @yatima2975: No.  They represent more complicated expressions, but they're independent and arbitrary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is similar to the other one.

If $a/b = m/n$ is rational then the equation can be written as $\cos (m\theta) = c \cos (n \theta)$ where $ax = m \theta$.  For $c = \pm 1$, $\theta$ will be an easily described angle, and if $|c| \neq 1$, then $\cos(\theta)$ is an algebraic function of $c$ since the equation is equivalent to $P_m(\cos \theta) = P_n( \cos \theta)$ where the $P$ are Chebyshev polynomials.  If $c$ is an algebraic number then so is $\cos(\theta)$.

For $a/b$ irrational and $c \neq \pm 1$ there is no algebraic solution.

Comment: Your last statement is a bit confusing: it must be interpreted as "there is no algebraic method of solution", not "there is no algebraic number that is a solution".

Comment: @Robert: yes, though actually I meant something stronger like "it is expected that the solution is not in a finite extension field of $Q(a,b,c)$, assuming as many standard conjectures as needed from transcendental number theory".